Motor plugin in ROS2
I want to build a self-balancing robot. In the simulation of this robot, I need to have a motor plugin that allows me to set the wheel speeds and accurately implement the mathematical model of this system in Gazebo.
Now, my question is, how should I do this when there is no motor plugin available in Gazebo? Yes, I know I can simulate the robot's linear speed using the diff_drive plugin, but what I need is the movement of the wheels, not the linear movement of the robot.
I also know that there is such a plugin to simulate the motor in ROS1, but not in ROS2.
